# xml:lang attribute for <html> tag effects SEO?

Tags: html, lang

I have a concern regarding `xml:lang` attribute for `<html>` tag.

Is really needed to boost SEO?

I am changing my `<html>` tag to `<html lang="en" xml:lang="en">`

Google looks for this declaration when interpreting organic search results?

Answer (score 3):

Specifying your content language always helps, but there's no point specifying `xml:lang` when you already have `lang`, since you're not writing XHTML.

So no, `xml:lang` is not needed.